# Can $_GET['foo'] param be simulated?

Tags: php

I have a function that uses its own params but also checks if any get/post values are avaliabe for different behavior.

I'd like to be able to do that in the home page, which url is: domain.com/

For example:

```
function simulate_get($name,$val){
// do it
}
```

And then, in code

```
..
simulate('foo','last_posts');
show_user_posts($user,$bla,$ble);
..
```

I know that I should add an extra paramerter to the function but still wondering if is actually posible in PHP to do that.

Comment: $_GET['foo'] = 'Any value'; ... Would it simulate what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write to it:

```
function simulate_get($name, $val)
{
    $_GET[$name] = $val;
}
```

Comment: I guess it looked too easy, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As **$_GET** is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) you can just do:

```
$_GET['foo'] = 'last_posts';
```

and then directly use it in your code:

```
$_GET['foo'] = 'last_posts';
show_user_posts($user,$bla,$ble);
```

or if you want to use a function to set it:

```
function simulate_get ($key, $value) {
    $_GET[$key] = $value;
}

simulate_get('foo','last_posts');
show_user_posts($user,$bla,$ble);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the contents of $_GET, that's no problem at all.

```
$_GET['foo'] = 'last_posts';
```